# How to compare only day and month in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date in a this first field: `2020-07-25` and another date in the second field: `2019-09-21`, now I want to compare if the date in the first field is before the date in the second field but only using day and month, I know that using the function `MONTH()` and `DAY()` can extract them, but how to compare them after ? This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE MONTH(FirstDate) < MONTH (SecondDate) AND DAY(FirstDate) < DAY(SecondDate)
```

Comment: Your table has date _columns_. (And a date has a year _field_, a month _field_ and a day _field_.)

Comment: Basic boolean logic problem. Your condition on day is not valid because the logic depends on the month. If the month logic succeeds, the comparison of day is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE MONTH(FirstDate) < MONTH (SecondDate)
   OR MONTH(FirstDate) = MONTH (SecondDate) AND DAY(FirstDate) < DAY(SecondDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you compare the dates without the year part. In this situation another posible option is to generate and compare new dates using `DATEFROMPARTS()` and a leap year as `year` part:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
   ('20200725', '20190921'),
   ('20200229', '20160729')
) v (FirstDate, SecondDate)
WHERE 
   DATEFROMPARTS(2000, MONTH(FirstDate), DAY(FirstDate)) <
   DATEFROMPARTS(2000, MONTH(SecondDate), DAY(SecondDate))
```

Comment: That won't work if SecondDate is 29 Feb and FirstDate is not in a leap year

Comment: Good catch, @sabik. I modified the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by constructing a single value as an integer or string:

```
where month(firstdate) * 100 + day(firstdate) < month(seconddate) * 100) + day(seconddate)
```

Or:

```
where format(firstdate, 'MMdd') < format(secondate, 'MMdd')
```

Answer (score 0):

A date (according to your example) is before another date when:

```
Month[1] < Month[2]

Month[1] == Month[2] && Day[1] < Day[2]
```

So this yields in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATES
WHERE MONTH(datum) < MONTH('2019-09-21')
OR (MONTH(datum) = Month('2019-09-21') AND DAY(datum) < DAY('2019-09-21'))
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aaf5f/1)